# Response code 500 (Explorer) or 200 (Chrome) for method openStream() on https rest service

Tags: java

I have this strange behaviour for this rest service:

https://apps.arpae.it/REST/qa_stazioni?max_results=1&page=1

With explorer i received the 500 response code but with other browsers like chrome it works perfectly and i can see the xml as result.

With java, the language that i use to interact with this server, i have the same problems of explorer. The code is pretty simple:

`URL site = new URL("https://apps.arpae.it/REST/qa_stazioni?max_results=1&page=1");
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(site.openStream(), "UTF-8"));`

I can't understand why my java code works like explorer and i've searched other solutions... but at the moment i still have this problem. I think that if chrome can read it, probably, i can read it with java too... but how?

Thank you in advance for your answers ^^

Comment: Is the SSL certificate CA trusted by Java?  Had this issue recently, a untrusted SSL cert was throwing an exception and generating a 500

Comment: Yes its trusted. If i try to access this one works perfectly:

https://apps.arpae.it/REST

Answer (score 0):

It appears chrome sends additional headers that are missing from Explorer

from chrome 
`Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8`

from explorer 11:

`Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/jxr, */*`

and encoding is different in the request headers as well chorme has:gzip, deflate, **br**
where IE is missing br encoding.

that's what I can see quickly at a glance. If you have access to the logs it's an internal 500 so if you can step through and see the exception on the server that will give you a better answer

*Edit*: make sure to add Request headers accept `application/xml` since it's an xml document that's being returned.